# Pointer, Arrays, Structs, Getchar: C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

One of the functions of my program must be to add a structure element in an array with 1000 members, in my struct stay 'matrnr' as integer,'name' with pointer as char and 'abslv' as array with 30 elements,because I must write characterstring using char and the size of the signs has to be declared, and pointer too,because the sum of all char-strings have to be smaller or equal to 30.

I am not allowed to use any library functions,only printf,getchar,scanf,cin and cout from iostream and stdio.h

My Questions about the struct:The name must also be implement with char,do I have to write array?

```
const int maxstudenten = 1000;
const int MAX = 30;

struct student_t {
    int matrnr; 
    char* name[MAX];  
    char** abslv[MAX];

};
```

I have also problems in the following spaces in this function (In the comments):

```
          int land (student_t *feld[maxstudenten], int i) { //I is my counter for 
        //the current size
            student_t *pstudentanlegen= new student_t; //Write a new student
            printf("Matrikelnummer:....");   //Enrolment number
            std::cin>>pstudentanlegen->matrnr; //Stack->enrolment number
            if (pstudentanlegen->matrnr>1 && pstudentanlegen->matrnr<999999) {

    //the enrolment number must be >1 and <999999
                if (binaeresuche(&feld[maxstudenten],i,(pstudentanlegen->matrnr))!=0) { //It examins if a student with this name already exists
                    std::cout<<"Student mit diesem Matrikelnummer ist schon vorhanden"<<std::endl;   //Student with this enr.nr exists
                    return i;    
                }else {
                    printf("\nName:.....");
                    pstudentanlegen->name=getchar(); //Pointer->name 
        //Here I cant write anything although I have written getchar
                    std::cout<<std::endl;
                    int zaehler=0;
                    std::cout<<"Möchten Sie Lehrveranstantungen hinfügen? j=ja,n=nein"<<std::endl; 
//Do you want to add lectures?
                    char a;
                    std::cin>>a;




                if(a=='j' && zaehler<MAX) { //zaehler=my second counter
//for the lectures
                    std::cout<<"Lehrveranstaltung:"; //Lecture:
                    pstudentanlegen->abslv[MAX]=getchar();
     //insupportable types of allocation of int to char* [30]
                    zaehler++;
                }
                i++;
            } //Anhängen (sortiert nach Matrikelnummer)
     //add(sorted towards number)
            int position=0;
            while(position<maxstudenten && pstudentanlegen->matrnr>feld[position]->matrnr) { //Invalid conversion of int in char**
                position++;
            }


            }return i;
        }
```

Comment: Function names, variable names and comments in English. Proper indentation where needed. Only relevant parts of the code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is only a small part of my code,I post the whole function,because I wanted to show what makes this function,without the purpose are 2 or 3 lines of the code pointless,and I have actually written what is the meaning of the variables in the comments and at the beginning  :)

Comment: Would it be useful to define various functions, each that does one simple job, and returns the exact required details? Now, can you split the problem you have, into many simple functions, that combined give a useful result? Are you done?

Comment: According to the tasc,this must be one function,and the way it works: 1.Write student (student<=1000), 2.ad lectures(lectures for every student<=30, 3.Student structure sorted in the field with students